# How do I make scrollbars on eclipse dark?

Tags: eclipse, themes, scrollbar

When I use the *Dark* theme on eclipse, everything apart from the scrollbars goes dark grey. I know it's possible to have dark scrollbars because Visual Studio has them. I've been looking for ages but I can't find an answer, so is there actually a way to have dark scrollbars on Eclipse? (Mars)